# "isinstance() and not" vs "==" for checking x=()

Tags: python

I want an if-statement to check if `x` is an empty tuple.

Is there any significant advantage of writing the if-statement as

```py
if isinstance(x, tuple) and not x:
```

vs

```py
if x == ():
```

given the latter is shorter to write and simpler to read?

Comment: These do different things: the former checks whether `x` is an instance of `tuple` (or a subclass thereof) and whether `bool(x)` returns `False`, whereas the second invokes `x.__eq__(())`. If `x` is just `()`, then both will do. Otherwise, many things can happen.

Comment: Do you want to check whether `x` is *specifically* a tuple or do you want to know if `x` is (specifically or subtype of) a tuple? `isinstance` deals with inheritence.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `x` is an object that _isn't_ a tuple but implements a meaningful comparison operator against one? The right answer here really depends on developer intent; there is no such thing as an objective answer to this question with only the context given.

Comment: To be clear, in most cases I would use `==` myself, but it's not going to have identical behavior in every possible situation.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I want to check whether x is an empty tuple. I have clarified my question.

Comment: For comparison, change the tuple of `0`, or an empty string. If `()` is regarded simply as a value, `==` is fine. Potential problems arise since tuples are often used for collections, where lists may also come into play; do you now compare `x == () or x == []` (obviously, `if not x:` is more appropriate here).

Comment: For `x = ()`, both are almost identical, as is `if True:`. If you know what it is, you need no check. I think you should say what your `x` can be in general.

Comment: What's not to like `if not x:`?

Comment: @СергейКох It doesn't check the type. If `x = 0`, the comparison should fail.

Comment: Given the mention of "check whether x is an empty tuple": how much is about the tuple-ness of `x`? Would an empty list also suffice? Or another empty collection?

Comment: @SunBear If you strictly want to check that it is a tuple (i.e. no subclass) and is an empty tuple, you could do `if type(x) == type(()) and x == ()`. But that's often very restrictive and usually not what is wanted, which is why people are a bit skeptical. Most would assume a tuple subclass would be accepted in this case, or if the `__eq__` method was overridden to compare against empty tuples.

Comment: It's very un-Pythonic to check the type of a variable.  Just `if not x:` would be best.

Comment: As an example of where `if x == ():` can go wrong, `x = pandas.DataFrame([])` would raise an exception. You run the risk that `x.__eq__` or the resulting object's `__bool__` raises an exception because of type issues.

Comment: @MarkRansom That would give a wrong result for example for `x = []`.

Comment: Unless you are treating `()` as a `None`-like sentinel, I'm not sure how often you would *care* about the result of this comparison.

Comment: @KellyBundy that all depends on what you consider *wrong*.  The Pythonic way is to not care about an objects type, just whether it has the properties you care about.  If there's someplace further along where only a tuple will do, that's the place to raise an error.

Comment: @MarkRansom They already do check `not x`. All you've done is you removed their `isinstance(x, tuple)`, which they wouldn't even have done if they knew that `x` is always a tuple, indicating that it's **not** always a tuple. And since they want to *"check if x is an empty tuple"*, your way doesn't do that and is wrong for that.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm merely stating that it's wrong to care whether it's a tuple or not.  OP could come back and make a case that for them it's super important, but they haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More often than not, you rely on object interfaces rather than specific types, so just `if not x` is sufficient and this is the usual Pythonic expression (see comments by @СергейКох and @MarkRansom).

The advantage of the first case is that tuple subclasses will be accepted, which is usually what is expected in a duck-typed language.

The second one is checking whether `x` is comparable to `True` against an empty tuple, which could be true for any class that implements a valid `__eq__` method.

If neither of these is acceptable, then you need to first compare the strict type with `type` and then check if it's empty.

Here is an example of the differences:

```py
class Foo(tuple):
    pass


class Bar:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return len(other) == 0:


things = {'tuple': tuple(), 'Foo': Foo(), 'Bar': Bar() }

for name, thing in things.items():
    if thing == ():
        print(f"{name} is an empty object with __eq__ implementation against empty tuple")
    if isinstance(thing, tuple) and not thing:
        print(f"{name} is an empty tuple, or tuple subclass")
    if type(thing) == type(()) and thing == ():
        print(f"{name} is an empty tuple")
```

Output:

```
tuple is an empty object with __eq__ implementation against empty tuple
tuple is an empty tuple, or tuple subclass
tuple is an empty tuple
Foo is an empty object with __eq__ implementation against empty tuple
Foo is an empty tuple, or tuple subclass
Bar is an empty object with __eq__ implementation against empty tuple
```

So it all depends on how strict or loose you want to be with your comparison.

Comment: `if x == ():` is also checking whether the object's `__eq__` or the resulting object's `__bool__` raises an exception.

Comment: @tdelaney Not sure what you mean exactly. Changing the `__eq__` to `raise Exception()` will raise the exception.

Comment: What do you mean with "comparable"? I might say `(1, 2)` is comparable to an empty tuple, as I *am* able to compare them.

Comment: You said _The second one is just checking whether x is comparable to an empty tuple_ - but you'd also have to wrap `if x == ():` in a try/except block to catch the exceptions. Try `x = pandas.DataFrame([])`. You'll get an exception which would terminate a program that doesn't do that.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's true, clarified. It should be "comparable to `True` against an empty tuple"

Comment: Another example where they differ: `x = unittest.mock.ANY`

Comment: @tdelaney Ah, I see. Yes, that is true. It depends on how strict the checks should be to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `if x == ():` is that you assume the object in `x` won't raise an exception or that some non-tuple objects might be happy being compared with tuples. A good example of the former is `pandas.DataFrame`. I couldn't think of an example of the latter, except `collections.namedtuple` (which I don't think counts). But that doesn't mean they aren't out there.

If you really want to test for an empty `tuple`, be specific and use your first example.

Comment: namedtuple isn't an example for a non-tuple.